# Testing the Application class doesn't shutdown the application after the test is done

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My WPF application has an App class, and it inherits from System.Windows.Application.

Inside this class I have my exception handling that handles DispatcherUnhandledException, so any un handled exceptions may be caught and be presented to the user.

To test this I start my test with

```
//Arrange
app = new App();
```

and then I continue with the rest of the test setup.

Later on in my test I run this code:

```
//Act
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new MyDlg(RaiseArgumentNullException));
```

This triggers ApplicationStartup to be executed in the App class.

When my next test starts it also creates a new App class, and also uses the CurrentDispatcher.Invoke to create another type of exception. **However, the first Application seems to be running.**

If I run my two tests one by one, they work just fine. **But if I run them in sequence the second one fails.**

Does anyone have any idea of how to properly shut down the Application after the test is done?

I have tried the following ways to shut the application down, but it doesn't work.

```
static void CloseApp()
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}

Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new MyDlg(CloseApp));
app.Shutdown();
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Send);
```

This is how my code looks like:
    delegate void MyDlg();

```
static void RaiseArgumentNullException()
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException();
}

[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    //Arrange
    app = new App();
    //...

    //Act
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new MyDlg(RaiseArgumentNullException));

    //Assert....

    //Tear Down
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new MyDlg(CloseApp));
    app.Shutdown();
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Send);
}
```

And this is my App class:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        Startup += ApplicationStartup;
        DispatcherUnhandledException += AppDispatcherUnhandledException;
        Bootstrapper.InitializeIoc();
    }

    private void ApplicationStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do startup stuff
    }

    void AppDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        HandleException(e.Exception);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
//....
}
```

Comment: What makes you say it "seems to be running"? My initial thought was that nowhere have you started the application so nothing is pumping its dispatcher. I don't see a call to `Run()` anywhere in your code above - have you left something out?

Comment: The reason for me saying that it seems to be running, is that when I run my 2nd test it fails if I run them in sequence rather than starting the test runner (I'm using resharper for this) for the 1st test, verifying the result, and then starting the test runner for then 2nd test and and verifying this.

Answer (score 0):

The `Application` class does not allow more than one instance of `Application` (or any subclass) to be created per `AppDomain`. This is regardless of whether the `Application` is still running or not. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Application implements the singleton pattern to provide shared access
>   to its window, property, and resource scope services. Consequently,
>   only one instance of the Application class can be created per
>   AppDomain.

To work around this, you could create an `AppDomain` in each of your tests.

Comment: Thank you Kent. I have checked on AppDomains before posting my question here, but I am not able to find any example that is simple and is not for IIS. I just didn't find out how to create an AppDomain for each test, and how to use it within the tests.